# Confusing time zones when parsing dates in Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

TZ on my comp is GMT+5.

```
  final DateTime date1 = dtf.parseDateTime("1979-04-29");
  final DateTime date2 = dtf.parseDateTime("1979-05-12");
  final DateTime date3 = dtf.parseDateTime("1979-04-02");
  final DateTime date4 = dtf.parseDateTime("1979-04-15");
  System.err.println(date1.toString());
  System.err.println(date2.toString());
  System.err.println(date3.toString());
  System.err.println(date4.toString());
```

Output is

```
1979-04-29T00:00:00.000-05:00
1979-05-12T00:00:00.000-04:00
1979-04-02T00:00:00.000-05:00
1979-04-15T00:00:00.000-05:00
```

-04? Why?

If add

```
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT+5"));
```

before, then output will be

```
1979-04-29T00:00:00.000-05:00
1979-05-12T00:00:00.000-05:00
1979-04-02T00:00:00.000-05:00
1979-04-15T00:00:00.000-05:00
```

Comment: That would be called "Daylight Saving Time" : http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/1979.html

Comment: @BrianRoach - that would be called an answer.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet - I wasn't going to bother ... but decided to move it to one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be called "Daylight Saving Time" : http://timeanddate.com/time/dst/1979.html

At `02:00` on `1979-04-29` it changed to `-04:00`